# How to write VCL in varnish to do no caching

Tags: varnish

I need to write VCL in Varnish so to prevent caching under certain conditions like cookie value.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Write and load your own .vcl file to instruct varnish when to cache. By default, requests with cookies will not be cached.

You could start with the [Varnish tutorial](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/index.html), and don't hesitate to ask a more specific question on this site if you can't make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Place the following inside your vcl_recv:

```
# as soon as we have a NO_CACHE cookie pass request
if (req.http.cookie ~ "NO_CACHE=") {
    return (pass);
}
```