# Prevent varnish caching for a specific widget / plugin?

Tags: wordpress, caching, varnish

I have a weather widget on our homepage that uses the users IP to display current local weather. The issue is that the first person to land on the homepage sees the correct weather but then all other users see the first users weather.

Obviously the homepage gets a lot of traffic so turning the cache off on the page is not an option.

What steps do i need to take to not cache just that widget/plugin on the homepage? Since it is a widget that might some day appear on other pages it would be great if the whole thing could be exempt but I don't even have a clue how to start?

As an additional note, the widget makes an api request to a 3rd party service with the IP address as one of the parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have given answer to similar question.Hopefully this will help you.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478986/how-to-write-vcl-in-varnish-to-do-no-caching/25661417#25661417
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405185/geoip-not-working-in-varnish-because-client-ip-returns-2-ip-addresses/25660476#25660476

Answer (score 0):

If the IP address of the user is included in the homepage as it is returned to the user, you will not be able cache the page without the side-effect you are having.

My suggestion would be to try and get that IP address info to the widget in a separate request. You would need to load the homepage first, without the users IP included, and them make a 2nd request from your Javascript (You could use Ajax/Websockets etc) that gets the ip address from the server, updates the HTML for the widget and makes it display the weather.

It's more work, and the exact implementation will depend on how the widget works.

Hopefully this sends you in the right direction :)